# Campos Relacionados

Tags: python, django

Estoy realizando un sistema el cual tiene dos modelos relacionado

Modelo 1

```
class tipo(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField('Tipo de Pedido', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
```

Modelo 2

```
class pedido(models.Model):
    numero = models.CharField('Numero de Pedido',max_length=100, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    estado = models.ForeignKey(estado, verbose_name=("Estado"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fecha = models.DateField('Fecha del Pedido', blank=True)
    nombre = models.CharField('Nombre de Factura',max_length = 150, blank=False)
    apellidos = models.CharField('Apellido de Factura',max_length = 150, blank=True, null = True)
    tipo = models.ForeignKey(tipo, verbose_name=("Tipos de Pedidos"), on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    metodo = models.ForeignKey(metodo, verbose_name=("Metodo de Pago"), on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    imp_remb = models.DecimalField('Importe Rembolsado', max_length = 150, default=0.00, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    imp_pedido = models.DecimalField('Importe del Pedido', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, default=0.00, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,)
    imp_manejo_clasif = models.DecimalField('Importe de Manejo y Clasificación', max_length = 150, default=0.00, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    imp_carga = models.DecimalField('Importe Manejo de Carga', max_length = 150, default=0.00, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    imp_caja = models.DecimalField('Importe de Cajas', max_length = 150, default=0.00, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    imp_manejo_clasif_dest = models.DecimalField('Importe Manejo y Clasif Dest.', max_length = 150, default=0.00, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    imp_total = models.DecimalField('Importe Total', max_length = 150, default=0.00, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    imp_dif_manejo_clasif = models.DecimalField('Importe Diferencia Manejo_Clasificacion', max_length = 150, default=0.00, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
```

Todo bien con la insercion de datos en dichos modelos, pero al momento de realizar una función como la siguiente:

```
@property
    def manejo(self):
        if self.tipo == 'Presencial':
           return format_html('<a style="color:green">OK</a>')
        else:
            return format_html('<a style="color:red">Error Verifica el Tax</a>')
```

no me muestra ok en los registros con el valor Presencial en el campo tipo.
Que me pudiera estar faltando para que se ejecute bien ???

en espera de su ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Así como lo tienes la manera correcta de hacerlo seria:

```
@property
def manejo(self):
if self.tipo.nombre == 'Presencial':
   return format_html('<a style="color:green">OK</a>')
else:
    return format_html('<a style="color:red">Error Verifica el Tax</a>')
```

Ya que self.tipo es una instancia del modelo tipo, no una cadena de texto.